# What can be the effective use of "story cycle time" in PivotalTracker

Tags: agile, pivotal-tracker

We are using PivotalTracker as agile project management tool. There are some reports build around **Story Cycle Time**. What can be the effective use of it?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Lead Time and Cycle Time]

It can be used to identify long feedback cycles to shorten, impediments to be addressed, need for more shared understanding of items, large scope items that could be sliced more thinly, etc.

[Cycle Time Report](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/articles/analytics_cycle_time/)